# Doctrine migration: Just write SQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, migration, database-migration

During development of my Symfony projects, my entity model is changed multiple times. As I don't want to remove and add the whole database + re-import the data from production environment everytime, I use Doctrine migrations (specifically the [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)).

**But actually, I just need the SQL statements** without migration classes and without a table tracking the migration version.

So my steps are

1. `doctrine:migrations:diff`
2. `doctrine:migrations:migrate --write-sql`
3. Delete the DoctrineMigrations/VersionXYZ.php file
4. Ignore the line `INSERT INTO migration_versions ...` in the SQL file

## Question: How can I reduce those steps to a single step?

I.e. I'm looking for a single command that generates my SQL file without the `INSERT INTO migration_versions ...` line and without DoctrineMigration class.

---

Reasons for why I just want the SQL, for those who are interested:

- I have to check them, because I don't trust the bundle (due to bad experience in the past)
- By rule, we add the SQL statements to the documentation or VCS commit message
- We have a project for which we derived the entity classes form an existing database. Although Symfony / Doctrine derived those classes itself, the migration diff contains lots of changes before having changed anything on the entity classes yet. We cannot apply some of them to the existing database

Comment: `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` gives you SQL queries that need to be run. Isn't it what you need?

Comment: or write your own custom command

Answer (score 1):

Here the right command for what you want to do :

php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --dry-run

Comment: How does this remove the need for running `doctrine:migrations:diff` before and deleting the migration class file after?

Comment: You are totally correct I read your question too fast. Actually there is no way in a one line command to do what you wish. DoctrineMigration has been built with the fact of keep tracking your version number within the database and versionning all the sql change files.